# JPQL - select where 2 properties are in 2 values

Tags: jpa, jpql

I have this object:

```
public class MyObject {
    private String prop1;
    private String prop2;
    // getters and setters
}
```

In JPQL I need select items like this:

```
SELECT O
FROM MyObject O
WHERE ( O.prop1 = :val1 AND O.prop2 = :val2 )
   OR ( O.prop2 = :val1 AND O.prop1 = :val2 )
```

And my question is, if is possible to simplify that query? It is only for educational purposes. Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to do some sort of `reduction` of logical ops? Or just to have it shorter? Simplifying might also mean obfuscating if it is menat to be `for educational purposes` in a sense someone else should understand it.

Comment: @pirho for logic :)